# Zookeeper errors

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

I am using solr with zookeeper and see the following errors in zookeeper logs

Using zk 3.4.10 and solr 6.6

```
    EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1XXXXXXX, likely client has closed socket
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:239)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:203)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-04-28 06:24:59,939 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxn@1044] - Closed socket connection for client /10.40.96.193:46260 which had sessionid 0x1XXXXXXX
```

The zoo keeper config

```
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
```

Do these config values result in above exception? If yes, can someone explain whether we should increase or decrease initLimit & syncLimit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you comment where and how you are deploying ZooKeeper?  Depending on that we could comment about the need to increase initLimit/syncLimit. I know for our own personal EC2 deployment of zookeeper within an AWS region but across AZs we had to increase the limits

Comment: Solr & Zk are on separate ec2 instances but in same AZ. Is that the info you were looking for?

Comment: Is there a downside to increase limits?

Comment: It's worth trying but at some level you get false positives - zookeeper thinks the ensemble is OK but it's not. What ec2 types are you using?

Comment: both solr & zk  are M4 large. Part of the problem is that i dont know how to reproduce that issue. I tried running some small tests with lower & higher limits but didnt see the same error - so not sure if these are related

Comment: m4.large should be fine but networking can always be a bit unpredictable. I'd say for now go with larger limits and if it recurs open an incident with AWS to investigate the  EC2 nodes affected

Comment: One more thing - I do see the intermittent EndofstreamException littered through zk logs - but there was a 30 min window when this happened repeatedly.. and then went back to 'normal` . Any theories ? And btw thank you so much for help so far

Answer (score 0):

Those 3 config parameters only refer to the ZooKeeper servers (ensemble) and irrelevant to your exception.  They are for synchronization between the leader and the followers.

Your client connection exception is more likely caused by a network issue (maybe TCP keep alive settings).

See [ZooKeeper Administrator's Guide:Cluster options](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.9/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_clusterOptions) for more information on `initLimit` and `syncLimit`.